# Importing scss partials inside another scss partial

Tags: sass

can i import scss partials inside another scss partial? Eg- importing `_abc.scss` inside `_xyz.scss`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I import Partials into Partials in SASS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489868/can-i-import-partials-into-partials-in-sass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### yes, with this simple code (syntax) : `@import "anotherScssFile.scss";`

Consider you have two scss files together, called config.scss and main.scss, if you want to import the config.scss file in main.scss, you can add this code in the first line of your main.scss :

```
@import "./config.scss"; /* this is what you want! */
.
.
.
```

in your case code must be like this (in _xyz.scss):

```
@import "path_to_abc_container_directory/_abc.scss";
```